# OSMNX : How to plot nodes only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, osmnx

I've tried to plot a map with trees. These are nodes in openstreetmap so I'm wondering if it's possible to plot a map with nodes only, without edge between them ?

Here's my code:

```
place=['Saint-Egreve,France']
G = ox.graph_from_place(place,retain_all=True,truncate_by_edge=True,simplify=False, network_type='none',infrastructure='node[natural=tree]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

Returning error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 102, in <module>
    fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
  File "/home/syl20/.conda/envs/ox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/plot.py", line 362, in plot_graph
    west, south, east, north = edges.total_bounds
  File "/home/syl20/.conda/envs/ox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "/home/syl20/.conda/envs/ox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/base.py", line 523, in total_bounds
    return GeometryArray(self.geometry.values).total_bounds
  File "/home/syl20/.conda/envs/ox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "/home/syl20/.conda/envs/ox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 101, in _get_geometry
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.
```

Thank you for your precious help !

Sylvain

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

place = 'Saint-Egreve,France'
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place)

# Plot the streets
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(graph)

# Retrieve nodes and edges
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)
nodes.head()

# Plot the nodes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
nodes.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='black')
```

Comment: Hi William, thanks for helping but this code not doing what I want. `G=ox.graph_from_place(place,network_type='none',infrastructure='node[natural=tree]')` give me : _raise nx.NetworkXPointlessConcept(
networkx.exception.NetworkXPointlessConcept: Connectivity is undefined for the null graph._ , so I cannot plot anything.

Comment: Have a look at https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L6/retrieve_osm_data.html around chunk 13 perhaps.

Comment: No, it cannot work because trees are not mapped as POIs but as simple nodes. Thank's for sharing this link though, it helps me a lot for other problems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to get trees data with osmnx, but if the trees data is collected in **geopandas format**, and there is **geometry** column on it, it can be ploted in the same axes with the nodes data (the node data must be in geopandas format too) you have.

but make sure you plot both data in the same axes.

the code would be like this:
creating blank axes

`hf, ha = plt.subplots()`

the blank axes is 'ha'

plot nodes and trees into the blank axes

`nodes_data_in_geopandas_format.plot(color="blue", ax=ha)`
`trees_data_in_geopandas_format.plot(color="red", ax=ha)`